# Is it possible for Live SASS Compiler in VSCODE to compress specific sass file and leave others as expanded?

Tags: vscode-extensions, live-sass-compiler

As I have imported bootstrap scss, now while compiling in vscode through live sass compiler I want only bootstrap css to be compressed and other files to be expanded. Is there any patern or settings thought which it can be achieved.